Combine scrolling screenshot + audio + subtitle
Hi this is cross posted on the community forum too as I wasn't sure which was used more.
I'm attempting to use Zapier with Transloadit to take scrolling screenshot video and then combine said video with elevenlabs audio and burned in subtitles.
I've gotten it to work with scrolling video + elevenlabs audio but the moment I tried to burn in subtitles audio and subtitles won't get added and all I get is a scrolling video.
What am I doing wrong?
Screenshot of relevant part of Zap:
enter image description here
Assembly output:
enter image description here
Assembly code:
{
  "steps": {
    "screenshot": {
      "robot": "/html/convert",
      "result": false,
      "format": "png",
      "fullpage": false,
      "width": 720,
      "height": 1280,
      "url": "${fields.screenshot_url}"
    },
    "scroll": {
      "use": {
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "screenshot",
            "as": "image"
          }
        ]
      },
      "robot": "/video/merge",
      "result": true,
      "duration": 30,
      "ffmpeg": {
        "vf": "scroll=vertical=0.001",
        "f": "mp4",
        "pix_fmt": "yuv420p"
      },
      "ffmpeg_stack": "v6.0.0",
      "framerate": 30,
      "preset": "empty"
    },
    ":original": {
      "robot": "/upload/handle",
      "result": false
    },
    "video_filtered": {
      "use": ":original",
      "robot": "/file/filter",
      "result": true,
      "accepts": [
        [
          "${file.mime}",
          "regex",
          "video"
        ]
      ],
      "error_on_decline": false
    },
    "subtitle_filtered": {
      "use": ":original",
      "robot": "/file/filter",
      "result": true,
      "accepts": [
        [
          "${file.mime}",
          "regex",
          "application/x-subrip"
        ]
      ],
      "error_on_decline": false
    },
    "add_subtitles": {
      "robot": "/video/subtitle",
      "use": {
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "scroll",
            "as": "video"
          },
          {
            "name": "subtitle_filtered",
            "as": "subtitles"
          }
        ]
      },
      "preset": "ipad-high",
      "ffmpeg_stack": "v6.0.0",
      "subtitles_type": "burned",
      "font": "Arial",
      "border_color": "00000000",
      "font_color": "FFFFFF",
      "border_style": "box"
    },
    "add_audio": {
      "robot": "/video/encode",
      "use": {
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "add_subtitles",
            "as": "video"
          },
          {
            "name": ":original",
            "as": "audio"
          }
        ]
      },
      "preset": "ipad-high",
      "ffmpeg_stack": "v6.0.0",
      "ffmpeg": {
        "c:v": "copy",
        "c:a": "aac",
        "strict": "experimental"
      }
    },
    "store_video": {
      "use": [
        "add_audio"
      ],
      "robot": "/s3/store",
      "credentials": "raf",
      "path": "final_output/${file.url_name}"
    },
    "store_original": {
      "use": [
        ":original"
      ],
      "robot": "/s3/store",
      "credentials": "raf",
      "path": "originals/${file.url_name}"
    }
  }
}

This is the working version of just scrolling video + audio but before I tried to add subtitles
{
  "steps": {
    "screenshot": {
      "robot": "/html/convert",
      "result": false,
      "format": "png",
      "fullpage": false,
      "width": 720,
      "height": 1280,
      "url": "${fields.screenshot_url}"
    },
    "scroll": {
      "use": {
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "screenshot",
            "as": "image"
          }
        ]
      },
      "robot": "/video/merge",
      "result": true,
      "duration": 30,
      "ffmpeg": {
        "vf": "scroll=vertical:0.001",
        "f": "mp4",
        "pix_fmt": "yuv420p"
      },
      "ffmpeg_stack": "v6.0.0",
      "framerate": 30,
      "preset": "empty"
    },
    ":original": {
      "robot": "/upload/handle",
      "result": false
    },
    "merge_audio_video": {
      "use": {
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "scroll",
            "as": "video"
          },
          {
            "name": ":original",
            "as": "audio"
          }
        ]
      },
      "robot": "/video/merge",
      "result": true,
      "ffmpeg_stack": "v6.0.0",
      "preset": "ipad-high"
    },
    "store_video": {
      "use": [
        "merge_audio_video"
      ],
      "robot": "/s3/store",
      "credentials": "raf",
      "path": "final_output/${file.url_name}"
    },
    "store_original": {
      "use": [
        ":original"
      ],
      "robot": "/s3/store",
      "credentials": "raf",
      "path": "originals/${file.url_name}"
    }
  }
}


Could you please add "result": true to the "add_subtitles" and "subtitle_filtered" and ":original" steps? Does the result of ":original" have the mime type you are filtering for in the /file/filter step?

The issue here is that our Zapier SDK hydrates the files, and when it gets parsed within Transloadit, your .srt file is being recognised as a .txt file. I am currently looking into this issue.
A workaround would be to pass the direct media link of the .srt file as an Assembly Field Variable to the assembly, within your Zap, and use the /http/import robot to import the file. This
